# Is Large Objects heap collected

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, large-object-heap

I cant find information about Large Objects Heap. Everywhere is wrote that it isn't fragmented. But I heard that isn't collected.

I cant find some article which provide me this information.

So, is LOH collected (dead instances removed from memory) or isn't?

Comment: Google `LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode` and see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/10/04/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The large object heap is collected as well. I don't know where it says that it isn't fragmented. That's not true. It isn't compacted by default though.

If you want to override the default behavior you can set the [LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) flag, but keep in mind that compacting a large heap can be very time consuming.

Comment: What is different between fragmented and compacted?
I thought it is same.

Comment: If the heap is not compacted fragmenting can occur. Fragmenting basically means that the free memory is not a contiguous block.